# UIDocumentInteractionController button clicked

Tags: ios, email, events, printing, uidocumentinteraction

My application originally had a standard Action Sheet displaying options for Email and Print for a PDF that was being viewed.  I tracked these events using Google Analytics.

I've now replaced the action sheet with UIDocumentInteractionController to allow the PDFs to be opened in external apps.  This works fine, however, there doesn't seem to be a way to track the Email and Print events for my Google Analytics. I can easily track which app is opened using

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
```

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent function that I can use to track Email, Print, Copy, etc.  Does anyone know how I can determine if these buttons were clicked, or determine if one of those particular events were triggered?